# table are created in hbase shell are not detected in phoenix shell

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

When I create table by phoenix shell it is detected in hbase shell by command `list`, but the same is not identified in Phoenix.

Phoenix just detects tables that are created in phoenix shell in addition HBase default table.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Phoenix is case-sensitive and only identify those tables that have names in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **`create a view`** on top of HBase table to perform any query in Phoenix.

To create a view, you need to be in phoenix and issue create view command like below

```
CREATE VIEW "<table_name>" ( ROWKEY VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, "<column_family_name>"."<column_name>" <data_type>, "<column_family_name>"."<column_name>" <data_type> )
```

For more details you can check [How to use existing HBase table in Apache Phoenix](https://khodeprasad.wordpress.com/2016/07/26/how-to-use-existing-hbase-table-in-apache-phoenix/)